# wifi roaming in android os oreo 8.0

Tags: 8.0-oreo, roaming, mi-a1

I am checking the wifi roaming behaviour of android os, for this test my setup like this:

1. I have two APs (T1 and T2) having same SSID, channel and security configuration.
2. I am using Xiomi mi A1 phone with oreo 8.0 for testing roaming.
3. I connected my phone to first AP T1 and continuously moving towards T2, after some distance my phone disconnected from T1 and connected to 2nd AP T2.
4. Am using wifi-analyser app for checking the RSSI values of AP.

**my question is:**

1. At what RSSI value phone starts background scan?
2. What is absolute difference between the RSSI of the two AP's for roaming?

Anyone knows this behaviour please share your answer.